# Why does ErrorAction not support lambdas in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

So im currently doing some research on design concepts in PowerShell and was watching an [Interview with Jeffrey Snover](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Expert-to-Expert-Erik-Meijer-and-Jeffrey-Snover-Inside-PowerShell). At about 30 Minutes he talks about error actions and that you can put Stop, Continue, SilentlyContinue, Ignore, or Inquire into the error action. This is currently supported. Example:

```
Stop-Process 0 -ErrorAction Stop
```

However, he also talks about the possibility of putting a lambda (script block) as an error action. Example:

```
Stop-Process 0 -Erroraction { <# Some code that gets executed in case of an error #> }
```

As of today this is (as far as i know) not yet supported. Is there a reason for this? I can not seem to find any other sources that talk about the possibility of lambdas as error actions.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you consider a lambda in PowerShell?

Comment: I guess the correct way to call it in PowerShell is a script block.
So for example something like
    $foo = { Write-Host "Hello" }

Comment: Oh, so you want to set the error action preference for a script block?

Comment: No, for example if i call the Stop-Process cmdlet i can specify an erroraction: Stop-Process 0 -ErrorAction Stop.
Why can i not do something like Stop-Process 0 -ErrorAction { Some code here }

Comment: How do you execute the script block?   There are several different methods.  The most appropriate method would depend on how you execute it.  

Some methods of executing the script block cause it to be executed in the current scope and some out of the current scope.  

I suggest rephrasing the question based on how you have tried to do this.  The results you are getting and the result you desire.

Comment: I am not asking how to do it, because it cannot be done. I am asking why it was not implemented. What are the reasons. Becaus Jeffrey Snover mentioned that he wanted to do it (in PowerShell version 2) but it apparently did not make it. I know this is a very specific question that only few can probably answer.

Comment: `New-Module { filter OnError { param([ScriptBlock]$lambda) if(($_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]) -and ($null -ne ($Property = $_.PSObject.Properties['WriteErrorStream'])) -and ($Property.Value -is [bool]) -and ($Property.Value)) { .$lambda } else { ,$_ } } } | Out-Null; Stop-Process 0 2>&1 | OnError { 'Shit happens' }`

Comment: I guess that works as a kind of workaround but it does not answer my question. Am i correct with the assumption that this solution to processing an error does not influence the pipeline as long as the script block does not write to the output stream? So we could pipe the output to any other cmdlet without it breaking?

Comment: *Am i correct with the assumption that this solution to processing an error does not influence the pipeline as long as the script block does not write to the output stream?* Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a `scriptblock` but you can use one.  You just need to say to evaluate it.  If you don't, since error action is a string, it will get the `ToString()` of the `scriptblock`

```
Write-Error 'test error' -ErrorAction (&{'Stop','Continue'|Get-Random})
```